# How to draw filled polygons?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, polygon

I would like to know how to draw filled polygons using CoreGraphics framework.

Here is example I am trying to draw:

[image]

I have A,B,C,D,E,F and G.

Can you suggest me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please just use comments under the individual answers, or edit your question if you want to provide more detail.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{      
    CGContextRef context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10, 50);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 80);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120, 120);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 60, 80);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 10, 50);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is no solution to make rounded corner. Trisha' your code draws a shape as first picture. AFAIK, on Android CornerPathEffect(int radius) class. This path effect draws rounded corner paths. Any suggestion like CornerPathEffect for iPhone ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this also with `UIKit` (i.e. higher level API):

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath ...];
...
[UIColor.redColor setFill];
[path fill];
```

This will fill your path i current graphics context.

Comment: Thank. But there is no solution to make rounded corner. Seems that your code is same as Trisha's. AFAIK, on Android CornerPathEffect(int radius) class. This path effect draws rounded corner paths. Any suggestion like CornerPathEffect for iPhone ? Thanks.